# Hacer 2 arrays y mostrarlos en un tercer array mezclados de 3 en 3 en java

Tags: java, array, bucles

Estoy tratando de  hacer un código en java en el que se declaran 2 arreglos de 12 elementos cada uno, para luego mostrarlos juntos de 3 en 3, es decir 3 elementos del arreglo 1, luego 3 elementos del arreglo 2 luego otros 3 del arreglo 1 y así sucesivamente, hasta completar un arreglo final de 24 elementos pero tengo un error que no permite que se imprima el arreglo final. El código es el siguiente:

```
package arreglosejercicio4;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArreglosEjercicio4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tabla1[], tabla2[], tablafinal[], incremento = 0;

        Scanner numeros = new Scanner(System.in);

        tabla1 = new int[12];
        tabla2 = new int[12];
        tablafinal = new int[24];

        System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de la tabla 1");
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
            tabla1[i] = numeros.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Inserte los elementos de la tabla 2");
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
            tabla2[i] = numeros.nextInt();
        }

        int j = 0;
        while(j < 24) {
            for(int a = 0; a <3; a++) {
                tablafinal[incremento] = tabla1[j + a];
                incremento ++;
            }
            for(int a =0; a <3; a++) {
                tablafinal[incremento] = tabla2[j + a]; //  El numero es igual a j (El numero total + a)
                incremento++;
            }
            j +=3;  // Aumenta el contador del array en 3
        }

        System.out.println("El arreglo final es: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <24; i++) {
            System.out.print(tablafinal[i] + "-");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Hay alguna otra forma mas fácil de hacer esto?

Comment: Esto es una tarea escolar?

Comment: Estoy tratando de aprender Java por mi cuenta!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desborda por lo siguiente: `j` lo vas incrementando de a `3` por cada ciclo del `while` para que te corra esas tres posiciones, todo muy lindo.. Pero fijate que pasa en esta linea: `tablafinal[incremento] = tabla1[j + a];` cuando el valor de `j` es **12**, en la primer iteración del for `a` vale **0** entonces **12+0=12** y ahí es donde desborda por que le estas diciendo que acceda a la **posición** o **índice** **12** del arreglo `tabla1`, el cuál no existe el **índice 12** ya que `tabla1` tiene **12 elementos**, o sea que va del **índice** **0 al 11**. Además fijate que lanza la excepción `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12`, que en español se traduce algo como "Índice fuera de los límites", y el **12** que te indica el índice inválido. Para solucionarlo reemplazá esto `while(j < 24)` por esto `while(incremento < 24)`, y mejor aún en vez de 24 le decís la longitud del arreglo, asi:
`while(incremento < tablafinal.length)`. Igual acá te paso el código mas limpio y tabulado para una mejor lectura:

```
public class Prueba268 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tabla1[]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23};
        int tabla2[]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24};
        int tablafinal[];
        tablafinal = new int[24];
        int incremento = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while(incremento < tablafinal.length) {
            for(int a = 0; a <3; a++) {
                tablafinal[incremento] = tabla1[j + a];
                incremento ++;
            }
            for(int a =0; a <3; a++) {
                tablafinal[incremento] = tabla2[j + a]; //  El numero es igual a j (El numero total + a)
                incremento++;
            }
            j +=3;  // Aumenta el contador del array en 3
        }
        System.out.println("El arreglo final es: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <24; i++) {
            System.out.print(tablafinal[i] + "-");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Errores tontos que tengo. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Es más fácil hacerlo de esta manera, el código es el siguiente:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i != 12; ++i)
    tablafinal[i] = tabla1[i];


for(j = -1; i != 24; ++i)
    tablafinal[i] = tabla2[++j];
```

Esto asigna los valores al arreglo final y no hay desborde, porqué cuando `i` vale 24, `j` es igual a 11 y eso hace que la condición finalice, por lo tanto, el bucle se rompe.